# Upsert in N1QL: How to count-up a value of an existing document

Tags: couchbase

I want to INSERT a document based on unique key or UPDATE a counter if the document already exists.

In the [UPSERT documentation of DP4](http://docs.couchbase.com/developer/n1ql-dp4/topics/upsert.html) I found an example that indicates that UPSERT is more like an INSERT or REPLACE.

```
UPSERT INTO product (KEY, VALUE) 
VALUES ("EAN1234567", 
        { "productId": "EAN1234567", "counter": 1}) 
RETURNING * ;
```

How can I increment the counter of an existing entry within an UPSERT?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the MERGE statement in N1QL.

MERGE INTO product p USING (SELECT NULL) s ON KEY your-key
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET p.counter = p.counter + 1
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT ...;

Comment: Yes, that solves my current issue. Thanks. But as I'm comparing `UPSERT` behavior in different databases I wonder if there is a possibility to use `UPSERT` for this task as well.

Comment: As you observed from the documentation, UPSERT in N1QL is INSERT or REPLACE. MERGE provides more options.